# How to structure get data from one array

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular6

My api results are showing this way. On my view i have one form section with many form group fields - like banner, logo, menu , footer. So how can i access banner section data for banner only and logo section data for logo only.

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    0: {id: "49ad6f11-d647-4947-b221-019322fe3f08", settingName: "Achievements", settingValue: null, dataType: "string", useFor: "Menu", …}
    1: {id: "ed54f6e9-cd0c-47cf-b8f7-2f58bc65dcf5", settingName: "Footer", settingValue: null, dataType: "string", useFor: "Footer", …}
    2: {id: "c6dc0c94-ae79-4150-b5ff-3efaf216dc56", settingName: "Logo", settingValue: null, dataType: "file", useFor: "Logo", …}
    3: {id: "3a2f41eb-cf20-42a5-bdbd-593e38dc05f3", settingName: "Title", settingValue: null, dataType: "string", useFor: "Title", …}
    4: {id: "87025725-b286-4013-b2de-6ee4c76b3393", settingName: "Banner Title", settingValue: null, dataType: "string", useFor: "Banner", …}
    5: {id: "c079bd1c-d098-41da-9cd4-7bb7f6bdf131", settingName: "Banner Image", settingValue: null, dataType: "file", useFor: "Banner", …}
    6: {id: "388d4d2b-e0bb-4e6a-8d61-ca6286e4f13c", settingName: "Banner Sub Title", settingValue: null, dataType: "string", useFor: "Banner", …}
    7: {id: "7a8098b3-2a79-4b84-afde-e5ec105098de", settingName: "Store", settingValue: null, dataType: "string", useFor: "Menu", …}
    8: {id: "e1efd155-867b-43be-8c82-ebcf48c0d3a0", settingName: "About", settingValue: null, dataType: "string", useFor: "Menu", …}
    9: {id: "6896130f-2d9d-43c7-9c8e-ecb24395cb04", settingName: "?", settingValue: null, dataType: "string", useFor: "Menu", …}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLqPv.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define model in such way that it will hold your UI structure.

In this case, I think you can group your response based on useFor to group similar catagery objects.

e.g.

```
{group key: group objects}
```

For UI, You can have dynamic componenet which will have two inputs:

1. group key i.e. value of useFor
2. group objects i.e. list of setting object.

Based on value of dataType you will have different components rendered on UI.

Regardin form based implementation. You can use same data structure to created Reactive Form modules which will have "id" of some unique name for each key with validations.
On UI, you will use same keys for binding.